# How to get row number in pickerview rowHeightForComponent?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a pickerview that may have different height of the row depends on the text on passed array:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: 44));
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.text = array[row]
    label.sizeToFit()

    return label;
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
    // How to get the the row number of pickerview here?
    return 0
}
```

Comment: You can set different height for same component rows

Comment: you cannot set different row heights for picker view. height set only for the component at once even you set different heights. refer -> https://github.com/anuradhss/PickerViews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a pickerview that may have different height of the row depends on the text on passed array

No, you don't have such a picker view. Picker views can't have variable row heights. The reason you can't find a way to do it is that there's no such way.